# Error in getting the status code of current page-PHP

Tags: php, sockets, http-status-code-404

Geting this is the snippet in php which I have managed

```
$server="localhost";
function sockAccess($page)
{
   $errno="";
   $errstr="";
   $fp=0;
   global $server;
   $fp=fsockopen($server,80,$errno,$errstr,30);

   if($fp===0)
   {
      die("Error $errstr ($errno)");
   }
   $out="GET /$page HTTP/1.1\r\n";
   $out.="Host: $server\r\n";
   $out.="Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";

   fwrite($fp,$out);
   $content=fgets($fp);
   $code=trim(substr($content,9,4));
   fclose($fp);
   return intval($code);
}
//echo '".'.$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"].'"';
//echo '"php self='. $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'"';
if(($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])}
{
echo "code=", " ", sockAccess('".'.$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"].'"'), "\n";
}
else
{
echo "code=", " ", sockAccess('".'.$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"].'"'), "\n";
}
echo "code=", " ", sockAccess("./test.php"), "\n";

echo "code=", " ", sockAccess("brokenlink.php"), "\n";
```

The problem is it still shows `code=404` for echo `"code=", " ", sockAccess('".'.$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"].'"'), "\n";`
So the solution which I think might be that it doesnt read the file which is already running.So i moditied the bove code by using if else thing.But now to file dosent run.Is this wrong.Thankx in advance.

Comment: sockAccess() basically return the status code of the page here.Its working fine with the manual page entry as given in the second line but not if request through $_SERVER thing.

Comment: what actually you get when var_dump($content) ??

Comment: can you paste value of $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] here ?

Comment: it comes out to ./test3.php....and test3.php is the page which contains only this code.

Comment: actaully it should output code=200...but the output is code=404

Comment: can you paste echo $content value when you call test3.php ?

Comment: yeah it gives o/p as content=HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 404

Comment: test3.php contains above socket connection code ? try to run test3.php directly from browser

Comment: yeah i did that and it doesnt give the desired o/p.